# Receiving an international letter in New Zealand with Parcel Collect

Tags: new-zealand, mail

I am currently travelling around the south island of NZ, and fate thought it would be hilarious if I suddenly needed to urgently receive some important documents from France.
However, I obviously don't have a long term address to send them to.

After a bit of resarch I found out about **Parcel Collect**, which is a service provided by the **NZ Post Group**. Apparently you can register on their website to get a special address in the town of your choice. When something arrives to that address, you get an email notification asking you to come an pick it up.
The only problem is that they don't mention anything whether you can use this service to receive letters from overseas.

Maybe I'm a bit paranoid, but I would really like to ask if anyone has ever used this service in such a way.
The only answer I got on the phone from the staff was basically a *shrug*.
If the letter would somehow get lost on the way, the consquences would be dire, and *costly*

Comment: The terms are quite clear that the service will not take letters at all, it's **parcel** collect for a reason. Those parcels must also be delivered by NZ Post or CourierPost, so unless you know they'll be the domestic service for your item, the parcel collect service won't help you either.

Comment: Have you considered [New Zealand Post's poste restante service](https://www.nzpost.co.nz/personal/receiving-mail/poste-restante)?

Comment: Why can't you send the documents via DHL to your hotel? It would only take 3-4 days and the hotel could receive the package in your absence.

Comment: I didn't know about DHL before. I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Contacting your country's embassy might be an option.

Alternatively, perhaps you could try contacting a Justice of the Peace near your location, and ask if they would be willing to receive your documents. It's not a common request I imagine, so you would probably need to assure them that the expected document is legal, and that they won't be asked to do anything that incurs a cost without being given money in advance (eg if you need the documents posted on, which costs). They *might* be willing to help.

Justices of the Peace are essentially highly trusted volunteers of a community who can be used to witness signing and certification of documents. They likely do other things I'm unaware of too.

You can do a search for Justices of the Peace by location on the yellow.co.nz phone directory website.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after calling the french post, the french ambassy, and going in person, twice, to a post office in New Zealand, it turns out that it is possible.
So yeah, I'm still confused, but I guess I'll try using Parcel Collect.
I'll edit the answer if I receive my documents without any problems. Thank you all for your answers!